# Why did Newton choose to devalue silve with respect to gold and (effectively) create the gold standard?

Tags: monetary-policy, exchange-rates, economic-history, china

This is a question of economic history, specifically about one specific event that caused the British to adopt the [gold standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_standard).

Reading about the gold standard one often encounters statements like this.

> Great Britain accidentally adopted a de facto gold standard in 1717 when Sir Isaac Newton, then-master of the Royal Mint, set the exchange rate of silver to gold too low, thus causing silver coins to go out of circulation.

To my understanding what Newton did was to change the exchange rate (of the [Bi-metallic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimetallism) system) between gold and silver from 1:20 to 1:21 i.e. making one gold guinea coin no longer equal to 20 silver shillings but 21 shillings instead. This gave gold a slight *edge* compared to silver so most people started buying gold instead of silver effectively creating the gold standard.

The question is why did he do this?
I'm looking for a historical reference, a book, or an article that deals with this question. Is it even known, or can his reasoning be somehow extrapolated from the historical records that we have?

There are several explanations I managed to find online

- 1. He performed chemical experiments on silver and gold and based on some *objective* physical properties of mass, malleability, ductility etc. decided that the right ratio is 1:21
- 2. Britain and Europe in general had a trade deficit with China which made it beneficial because the Chinese used a copper-silver bimetallic system which effectively allowed the British to sell the Chinese their silver on their market and to substitute it with gold because of the [Brazilian gold rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Gold_Rush).
- some combination of the two or some other deeper reason...

Again, I would like to find a serious article or book that deals with the explanation of the (effective) adoption of the gold standard. Everything I have is a combination of Wikipedia and Encyclopedia Britannica articles and an elementary ability to string facts together.